# Unable to stream a .m3U8 file

Tags: ios, audio-streaming, http-live-streaming

I have an iOS streaming app. It works fine for my streaming urls. How can I use AudioStreamer for .m3u8 file url?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why you need `AudioStreamer` when you already have `AVPlayer` to play your live Audio/Video streams? Use `AVPlayer` to stream audio.

Answer (score 1):

Why you need to use `AudioStreamer` class when you can do it with `AVPlayer` easily, Though `AudioStreamer` uses `AVPlayer` internally.

Following code plays live streaming audio using `AVPlayer`, you can change source URL to embed your stream.

> Don't forget to add AVFoundation.framework in your `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` section under Project->Target->Linked Frameworks and Libraries

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController ()
{
    AVPlayerItem * mPlayerItem;
}

@property (readwrite, retain, setter=setPlayer:, getter=player) AVPlayer* mPlayer;
@property (strong) AVPlayerItem *mPlayerItem;

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize mPlayer;
@synthesize mPlayerItem;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // *** Initialise player and register observer ***
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"];

    self.mPlayerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];

    self.mPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:self.mPlayerItem];

    // *** Add Observer on AVPlayerItem to observer progress & status ***
    [self.mPlayerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];

    [self.mPlayer play];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if (object == self.mPlayerItem && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"])
    {
        if (self.mPlayer.currentItem.status == AVPlayerItemStatusFailed)
        {
            NSLog(@"------player item failed:%@",self.mPlayer.currentItem.error);
        }
        else if (self.mPlayer.currentItem.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay)
        {
            NSLog(@"Play");
            [self.mPlayer play];
        }
        else if (self.mPlayer.currentItem.status == AVPlayerStatusFailed)
        {
            // something went wrong. player.error should contain some information
            NSLog(@"Unable to play.");
            NSLog(@"%@",self.mPlayer.error);
        }
        else if (self.mPlayer.currentItem.status == AVPlayerItemStatusUnknown)
        {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayer Unknown");
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it helps you to understand, there are lot of stuffs you can do with `AVPlayer` in given code. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Try and parse the m3u8 file and get the actual URL to the resource and then pass that URL to AudioStreamer.

Here -> https://github.com/Achillesun/M3U8Paser you can find M3U8Parser lib that parse the playlist.

Below is an example of m3u8 format:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10

#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1

#EXTINF:10,
http://video.example.com/segment0.ts
#EXTINF:10,
http://video.example.com/segment1.ts
#EXTINF:10,
http://video.example.com/segment2.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```